# High frequency info modulation in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to modulate high frequency contents in an image to achieve the result shown in the attached image?

I tried some filter but I only get edges not this type of image.

Example Image:

[image: Exampleimage]

```
I=imread('cameraman.tif')
J=unint8(filter2(fspecial ('laplacian'),I));
K=imlincomb(1,I,-1,J);
```

[image: RESULTS]

Comment: convolve with a laplacian filter

Comment: imlincomb() with source image and Laplace filter of image

Comment: @Sam Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61808105/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Alex Alex I have tried what you told, but ain't working..please check the code I edited in my post and see what's missing

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5698672) and [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: Test this code:
J=filter2(fspecial ('laplacian'),I);
K=uint8(0.3*double(I)+64-0.3*J);

Comment: @Alex Alex, thanks yeah it's working. Can you please give some insight about how to control parameters to tune filtering of frequency components. And what have you done here

Comment: first 0.3 - contrast,  64-brightness (shift mean level), second 0.3 - power of edge.

Comment: THANKS can you tell me setting for an image with pixel values between 0-1 not 0-255. How can I set weights  for K=uint8(0.3*double(I)+64-0.3*J)

Comment: Also please check the image in my post for your method. How can I reach the desired result. I tried to change the settings of contrast to reach somewhat nearby.